# prolog logic gates aggregation recursion optimisation

Tags: prolog, query-optimization, aggregation

I am trying to implement a logic gate type aggregation operation. And I am having trouble with writing an implementation that perform the calculations in a reasonable amount of time. I think what I have works logically but it is very slow and I don't think it needs to be. I think it should be possible to do this with out using to many 'findall's or cuts'.

I have a table of approximately 10,000 columns and 70 rows. The rows correspond to samples and the columns to probes. Each value in the table is either a one or a zero (the state of the probe in the sample).

Multiple probes code for a protein. (Many to one relationship) So I want to aggregate the probe columns to protein columns with a Logical OR operation.

In addition to this some proteins are a part of a protein complex or a protein set. Both protein complexes and protein sets in addition to containing proteins may in turn contain protein complexes or protein sets. So they can be a kind of a recursive relation. I want to model protein sets as OR gates and protein complexes as AND gates. Collectively I refer to proteins, protein_sets and complexes as 'Entities'.

So over all I want to have a predicate where I can ask if a protein or entity is on or off in a sample that works quickly.

If some of the other predicates are not clear then I can tell you what they do.

```
protein(Sample, Reactome_Id, State):-
    setof(Sample, Probe^samples(Sample, Probe, ProbeValue), Samples), 
    %sample/3 is a set of facts that correspond to the described table
    member(X, Samples), %used to generate Sample Id's %this seems wasteful 
    protein_reactome_Id_to_Uniprot_Id(Reactome_Id, UniprotId), % a set of facts matching two types of id
    %used to generate uniprot ids
    findall(Value, uniProt_Sample_Probes(UniprotId,X,_,Value),Vs),
    Vs = [_|_],     %Check list is not empty already
    delete(Vs,0,ListOfOnes),
    (ListOfOnes=[]-> (State is 0, write('OFF'));(State is 1,write('ON'))).
    %As this is an or I think I should just be able to find a single 1 and cut for the  on case and if this is not possible to say it is off.

%if a (simple) entity is a protein set and its state is on
%this is a base case where an entity does not have complexs or sets inside it
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    all_children_proteins(Entity), %checks that all children are of type protein
    type(Entity, protein_set),
    child_component(Entity,Child), %generates the children of an entity
    protein(Sample,Child,1),
    State is 1,!.

 %if a (simple) entity is a protein set and it's state if off
 %this is a base case where an entity does not have complexs or sets inside it
 %I find all proteins for a sample, this is a list of values, I delete all the
 %zeros and the remaining list will unify with the empty list.
 state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
     all_children_proteins(Entity),
     type(Entity, protein_set),
     child_component(Entity,Child),
 bagof(Value, Value^protein(Sample,Child,Value),Vs),
 delete(Vs,0,ListOfOnes),ListOfOnes=[],
 State is 0,!.

%if a (simple) entity is a complex and is off
%this is a base case where an entity does not have complexs or sets inside it
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    all_children_proteins(Entity),
    type(Entity, complex),
    child_component(Entity,Child),
    protein(Sample,Child,0),
    State is 0,!.

%if a (simple) entity is a complex and is on.
%this is a base case where an entity does not have complexs or sets inside it
%I find all protein in a sample, this is a list of values, I delete all the
%zeros and the remaining list will unify with the empty list.
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    all_children_proteins(Entity),
    type(Entity, complex),
    child_component(Entity,Child),
    bagof(Value, Value^protein(Sample,Child,Value),Vs),
    delete(Vs,1,ListOfZeros),ListOfZeros=[],
    State is 1,!.

%if a complex with components is off
%recursive case
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    type(Entity, complex),
    child_component(Entity,Child),
    (state_of_entity(Child,0,Sample);
    protein(Sample,Child,0)), %if it has any proteins as input as well as other      components
    State is 0,!.

%if a complex with components is on
%recursive case
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    type(Entity, complex),
    child_component(Entity,Child),
    bagof(Value, Value^state_of_entity(Child,Value,Sample),Vs),%if it has component inputs
    bagof(Value2, Value2^protein(Sample,Child,Value2),Vs2),%if it has protein inputs
    append(Vs, Vs2, Vs3),
    delete(Vs3,1,ListOfZeros),ListOfZeros=[],%delete all the ones, the list of zeros will be empty if all inputs are on
  State is 1,!.

%if a protein set with components is on
%recursive case
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    type(Entity, protein_set),
    child_component(Entity,Child),
    (state_of_entity(Child,1,Sample);
    protein(Sample,Child,1)), %if it has any proteins as input as well as other entities
    State is 1,!.

%if a protein set with components is off
%recursive case
state_of_entity(Entity,State,Sample):-
    type(Entity, protein_set),
    child_component(Entity,Child),
    bagof(Value, Value^state_of_entity(Child,Value,Sample),Vs), %if it has entity inputs
    bagof(Value2, Value2^protein(Sample,Child,Value2),Vs2), %if it has protein inputs
    append(Vs, Vs2, Vs3), %join the list of inputs together
    delete(Vs3,0,ListOfOnes),ListOfOnes=[], %delete all the zeros, the list of 1's will be empty if all inputs are off
    State is 0,!.
```

***Update***
I ended up with this for the protein bit to work as I wanted.

```
samples(Samples):-
    setof(Sample_in, Probe^samples(Sample_in, Probe, ProbeValue), Samples).
sample(Sample):-
    once(samples(Samples)), %why do I need this?!
    member(Sample, Samples).

protein_stack(Sample, Reactome_Id, State):-
        (
            protein_reactome_Id_to_Uniprot_Id(Reactome_Id, UniprotId),
            uniProt_Sample_Probes(UniprotId, Sample, Probe, 1),
            !,
            State is 1
        ;
            State is 0
        ).

protein_good(Sample, Reactome_Id,State):-
    sample(Sample), 
    protein_reactome_Id_to_Uniprot_Id(Reactome_Id, _),
    protein_stack(Sample, Reactome_Id,State).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the first rule for `protein/3`.

- Is the relation between `Reactome_Id` and `UniprotId` unique? If yes, move it before `setof(Sample ...), member(X, Samples)` and put a cut after it. Otherwise you would try to satisfy it for every result of `setof(...), member(X, Samples)`. More than that, a green cut helps in terms of performance.
- The rule has one purpose, to see if there is at least one value of 1 in `Vs`. You should not generate all members of `Vs` and then search for a value of 1, but stop when you find the first one as you satisfy `uniProt_Sample_Probes(UniprotId, X, _, Value)`.

  ```
  protein(Sample, Reactome_Id, State):-
          (
              protein_reactome_Id_to_Uniprot_Id(Reactome_Id, UniprotId),
              setof(Sample, Probe^samples(Sample, Probe, ProbeValue), Samples), 
              member(X, Samples),
              uniProt_Sample_Probes(UniprotId, X, _, 1),
              !,
              State is 1, write('ON))
          ;
              State is 0, write('OFF')
          ).
  ```

The other rules can be optimized using the same pattern:

```
state_of_x(X, State) :- Goal, !, State = 1.
state_of_x(X, State) :- State = 0.
```

or, more concise,

```
state_of_x(X, 1) :- Goal, !.
state_of_x(X, 0).
```